# Facebook graph API search alternative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So FB said that their page search is deprecated (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching), but they absolutely refuse to state any alternatives (or I could not find them).

Is there one or did they just straight up remove this feature and we can no longer use any API functions to search for pages?

Comment: _“So FB said that their page search is deprecated”_ - where?

Comment: https://imgur.com/rRzGLBU

Comment: Totally different thing. That is referring to the old, global search endpoint, accessed via `/search?type=place`. `/pages/search` is a different animal altogether.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I thought that was the same thing. Alright, thanks for clearing that up for me!